# ElasticSearch/Tire: Find similar articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, tire

My Rails project implements the ElasticSearch using the Tire gem. I would like to find records with similar text in a field called description. I would like to order results based on how similar the record is (%).

Example of a similar tekst:
1. Hi my name is Tom and I like cars.
2. Hey I'm Tom. I like cars.
3. Tommy like to play with cars.

Please help me configure the model. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Elasticsearch, you can use the ["more like this"](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/more-like-this.html) API, to find similar documents.

In Tire, you can use the [`more_like_this`](https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib/blob/master/lib/tire/queries/more_like_this/more_like_this.rb) query, passing it the text. See the [test case](https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib/blob/master/test/queries/more_like_this/more_like_this_test.rb) for documentation.

Comment: Is there anyway to pass in a document ID versus text for more like this queries?

Comment: It is possible to query a document in elasticsearch for mlt but in tire isn't it a search with an mlt query in? The latter doesn't support specifying a document id.